# MDT 2013 WinPE File Name

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, mdt, mdt-2013

In MDT 2013, is there a way to change the file name of the WinPE WIM that's generated from updating the share?

I'm going to be using multiple deployment shares with WDS, and I was trying to automate importing the WinPE WIMs into WDS. I know you can change the image name, but it would be easier for the WIM file name to be different from LiteTouchPE_x64 (or x86). I was thinking about just adding an rni line to the PS script for auto importing to WDS, but I wasn't sure if it would cause any issues if I manually renamed the WIM file.

Comment: Are you referring to automatically generating a file with a certain name or just about manually renaming WIM files?

Answer (score 0):

Manually renaming the file is not a problem.

Changing the name in the deployment properties only changes the description, but not the filename I presume?

Since you are importing the Images in WDS, what does the original WIM-containers file matter? I would assume the image name matters but the filename seems irrelevant to me.

Comment: I was modifying a PowerShell script to copy the boot image to the WDS folder, and I didn't want the boot image from Company A to overwrite the boot image from Company B. I ended up adding a line;    cpi X:\CompanyA\Boot\LiteTouchPE_x64.wim X:\RemoteInstall\Boot\x64\Images\CompanyA.wim  to the script that gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot change the name of the image that is automatically generated in MDT.

You can safely change the name of the outputted WIM file without affecting anything.

When WDS imports a boot image it renames it to boot.wim on the inside of the WDS file storage system, so the filename that MDT outputs is really only for the sysadmin.

It is the image name and description that really counts. I would change those as WDS automatically gathers that info upon image import (using the GUI) and that is what you see when manipulating the images.